# Load orm xml from External Jar into Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a maven spring project called core-project jar which has orm and persistence xml files and defined entities both in Annotation and xml.
Now I have another spring boot project which utilizes this core project to initialize persistence with.
I am able to get the annotated entities(i.e with `@Entity`) scanned when defining @EntityScan(packages) in SpringBoot Main class but none of the entities are scanned which are defined in orm xml (i.e `<entity>`).

Getting error as 
`Unable to locate persister for entity`

But when I run the same project as mvn spring-boot:run , everything runs like charm. When I do a java -jar I end up in above issue.

I have tried setting up LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and setting packages to scan but no luck.

Let me know what needs to done for a spring boot to load orm xml based entities from external jar.

Note: orm and persistence xmls are part of core-project, we dont want it in spring boot project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create a `persistence.xml` in the Spring Boot project to reference the jar file:

```
<jar-file>core.jar</jar-file>
```

I never done that with spring boot but maybe this works as well as with "normal" Java EE apps.

Comment: Excellent. I have tried this and it worked out. Though I have do some Bean creation of EntityManager but eventually this worked !! Thanks

Comment: I'm happy I could help you.